# How to rank event times by a given time window using SQL?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto, gaps-and-islands

I am struggling to find a way to rank the events using SQL.
The goal is to increment the rank whenever an event occurred more than `delta` seconds (e.g. 1 second) from the previous observation. So far my attempt is shown below:

```
select a.event_time, a.user_name, a.object_name, a.rnk, case when a.ddif <= 1000 then 0 else 1 end as new_query,
            case when a.ddif <= 1000 then 0 else rnk end as new_rnk
from (
    select *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY event_time) AS rnk,
              date_diff('second',lag(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY event_time),event_time) as ddif
    from tmp
    ) a
```

But it gives me just the following results and I still don't know how to achieve the results in `yellow` (either of them works for me perfectly).

[image]

I'd appreciate any help with that.

Please note: I am using **Presto DB**, hence I am limited to this query engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the good tips that pointed me the direction to the final solution which is:

```
select a.*, sum (case when a.ddif <= 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by user_name order by event_time) as acc_rnk
    from (
        select *, date_diff('second',lag(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY event_time),event_time) as ddif
        from tmp
        ) a
```

Comment: I was thinking about making use of `ceil` and `second` function but see you have a solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define the groups.  Then assign row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by user_name, grp order by event_time) as seqnum
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_et > event_time - interval '1' second
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by user_name order by event_time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(event_time) over (partition by user_name order by event_time) as prev_et
            from tmp t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks! It was very close to the final working solution which I am sharing below (so that other Presto users could reproduce it).

Comment: @mrjoseph . . . I think that directly comparison the timestamps is better than `date_diff()`.   I *think* that function returns the number of "boundaries", so a value of "1" could be 0.1 seconds or 1.9 seconds.

Comment: I guess you're right - please just note that in presto there is a bit different syntax for the intervals, should be: interval '1' second, but the rest is fine, thanks! btw. in my case date_diff should work as I don't have the millisecond part of the timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` and a window `sum()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(case when event_time <= lag_event_time + interval '1' second then 0 else 1 end) rnk 
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(event_time) over(order by event_time partition by user_name) lag_event_time
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the good hint, however sum needs to have partition by or group by, nevertheless it pointed me the right way towards the solution.

Comment: @mrjoseph: welcome. I just added the `partition` clause to the window function. It was not obvious in your sample data all rows have the same `user_name` and `object_name`